# How to stop logic in another method in java

Tags: java

My logic is basicly like that;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    check("This is string");

    System.out.println("logic continue");

}


private static void check(String text) {

    if (text.equals("This is string")) {
        System.out.println("true");
    } else {
        System.out.println("false");
    }
}
```

I want to check the logic in another method and if statement is "false" i dont want to return the calling method.

For example;

In "check" method, if strings are not equal, program/thread or something else must be finish and "logic continue" mustn't be written.

I want to use this logic in web service to check the headers. in doGet and doPost super method. If headers are not correct, gives a custom exception and program does not continue by sub class.

```
Thread.currentThread().stop();
```

above code (Therad.currentThread().stop()) does not working in sevlet.

Can anybody know this methodology in a safe way ?

EDIT :

Some people understand me wrong so i wanted to edit my question. Below is what i want to do. I have servlets in dynamic web application. And all of these servlets extends myBaseServlet.

BaseServlet.java

```
public class BaseServlet extends HttpServlet{

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

    if(HeadersCheckHelpers.checkHeaders(httpServletRequest){

        //if this part is working, everthing fine, application does what it wants

    }else{
        // if this else block works, thread should be stopped and non-return the subclasses
    }
}
```

}

example sub servlet class

```
public class ContextServlet  extends BaseServlet{

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) {
    super.doGet(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);

    //if headers are not correct, i want this part not working. super class should handle this.
}
```

}

So again, if the logic is true or false, i want to stop process(i dont want to return subclass method).

Comment: return a boolean from that method, only print that if that boolean is true.
You can also close the application (System.exit(0);) in the else block

Comment: returning boolean value is not a logical way, all sub classes must have if-else block in this way. and there is no system.exit(0) chance in wer service

Comment: Since you want the next line to be performed, based on a condition checked in that method, returning a boolean IS the logical way. that's what booleans are for, after all.

Comment: that means, if you have 100 class extends same class, you have to write 100 if-else case

Comment: they inherit and re-use the method. so why?

Answer (score 0):

Declare method returning a `boolean` and check it when you call it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (check("This is string"))
        System.out.println("logic continue");
}


private boolean void check(String text) {

    if (text.equals("This is string")) {
        System.out.println("true");
        return true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("false");
        return false;
    }
}
```

**CLARIFICATION**: I don't know how new are you to java so this line

```
if (check("This is string"))
```

is the same as:

```
boolean result = check("This is string");
if (result == true)
```

Comment: I dont want to return value. just stop the logic in that method.

Comment: the method should be static, though :)

Answer (score 0):

In a Servlet request you must return always a response. In this case you should return a [4xx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error) Http Status:

```
if (!check("This is string")) {
    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
} else {
    System.out.println("logic continue");
}
```